# Using ruby variable in a PowerShell script with winrm

Tags: ruby, powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

**EDIT:**
I would like to count files/folders of storage containers via virtual machine manager PowerShell cmdlet.

I went over similar questions, but still am struggling with syntax.
I have a ruby script that is executing a PowerShell script on a remote server.
I want to use a ruby variable within the Powershel script. 
For example

```
path_str = "\\XXX\YYY\" #This is the ruby var

PSoutput = shell.run(" #This part is executing the PS script
            $Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path #{path_str}  | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}" | stdout
```

How do I use the ruby variable path_str with the PS script?
I have tried

# {path_str}

\" " + path_str + " \"

Double quotes and single quotes

Nothing worked for me.

Comment: What does "Nothing worked for me" mean? Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I see causing the issues.

1. `#` is a reserved character in powershell. When you use #, anything after that is a comment.
2. You are assigning the output of `Get-ChildItem` to `$files`. There will be no output from shell.run() to assign to PSoutput because output from cmdlet is getting assigned to `$files`.
3. `Get-ChildItem` is a powershell specific command, not a command line / dos command that you can execute from within shell, without first calling powershell executable. (this, I am a little doubtful on but quite sure its correct).

What you can do from ruby is, should work,

```rb
PSoutput = system("powershell get-childitem -Recurse -File -Path " + #{path_str} + "  | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}")
```

Once the command executes, you should have a total number of files under the #path_str directory.